# Getting NameIDPolicyError implementing SSO with ADFS 2.0

Tags: adfs2.0

I am trying to connect third party system with ADFS 2.0 using SSO. I created Relying party trust, and two claim rules

Rule #1

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress");
```

Rule #2

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"), query = ";mail;{0}", param = c.Value);
```

I am able to hit ADFS server but getting this error

```
MSIS1000: The SAML request contained a NameIDPolicy that was not satisfied by the issued token. Requested NameIDPolicy: AllowCreate: False Format: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress SPNameQualifier: https://xxx.xxx.com/sso. Actual NameID properties: null.
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Please post your solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This piece is the clue:

> SPNameQualifier: https://xxx.xxx.com/sso. Actual NameID properties:
>   null.

So the SP has a NameID (entity ID) of "https://xxx.xxx.com/sso" but there is no such name configured on the ADFS side.

You need to add this to the claim with the Properties [] construct.

Refer : [ADFS – SAML 2.0 Identity Provider and SaaS Service Providers](http://blog.auth360.net/2012/09/02/adfs-as-an-identity-provider-and-saml-2-0-saas-application-integration/).