# Configured ADFS with OpenAM -- NameID error

Tags: active-directory, saml-2.0, adfs

This question is very similar to a different post:

[Getting NameIDPolicyError implementing SSO with ADFS 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16403359/2957379)

However, the above answer did not work. I've read many posts on this site and others on how to fix this. Many people are able to get it working but I can't. The problem in short is that when we configure an OpenAM server as a relying party trust in AD  we get an SSO error after login.

> *Log Name:      AD FS 2.0/Admin Source:        AD FS 2.0 Date:          11/4/2013 12:52:04 PM Event ID:      321 Task Category: None Level:
>
>   Error Keywords:      AD FS User:          CBC\adfsuser Computer:
>
>   domainserver2.cincybible.priv Description: The SAML authentication
>   request had a NameID Policy that could not be satisfied.  Requestor:
>   sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com/ccuniversity_sso  Name identifier format:
>   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient  SPNameQualifier:
>   sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com/ccuniversity_sso  Exception details: 
>   MSIS1000: The SAML request contained a NameIDPolicy that was not
>   satisfied by the issued token. Requested NameIDPolicy: AllowCreate:
>   True Format: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient
>   SPNameQualifier: sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com/ccuniversity_sso. Actual
>   NameID properties: null.  This request failed.*

We have created Issuance Transform Rules as directed by all of the articles we have found online. We've tried many versions of this, but this is our latest attempt.

**The first rule:**

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient", Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/spnamequalifier"] = "http://sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com/ccuniversity_sso", Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/namequalifier"] = "http://auth.ccuniversity.edu/adfs/services/trust");
```

**The second rule:**

```
c:[Type == "http://mycompany/internal/sessionid"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient");
```

**Here is the output from Get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust:**

```
AutoUpdateEnabled                    : False
DelegationAuthorizationRules         : 
EncryptionCertificateRevocationCheck : CheckChainExcludeRoot
IssuanceAuthorizationRules           : @RuleTemplate = "AllowAllAuthzRule"
                                        => issue(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/permit", Val
                                       ue = "true");


SigningCertificateRevocationCheck    : CheckChainExcludeRoot
WSFedEndpoint                        : 
IssuanceTransformRules               : @RuleName = "tma1"
                                       c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier
                                       "]
                                        => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameiden
                                       tifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, 
                                       ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/ident
                                       ity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transi
                                       ent", Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties
                                       /spnamequalifier"] = "http://sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com/ccuniversity_sso", Prop
                                       erties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/namequali
                                       fier"] = "http://auth.ccuniversity.edu/adfs/services/trust");

                                       @RuleTemplate = "MapClaims"
                                       @RuleName = "tms"
                                       c:[Type == "http://mycompany/internal/sessionid"]
                                        => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameiden
                                       tifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, 
                                       ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/ident
                                       ity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transi
                                       ent");


ClaimsAccepted                       : {}
ConflictWithPublishedPolicy          : False
EncryptClaims                        : True
Enabled                              : True
EncryptionCertificate                : [Subject]
                                         CN=*.uat.firstmarblehead.com, OU=Information Technology, O="First Marblehead E
                                       ducation Resources, Inc.", L=Boston, S=Massachusetts, C=US

                                       [Issuer]
                                         CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US

                                       [Serial Number]
                                         098E9D684BFAE209A18CCEF5787321DC

                                       [Not Before]
                                         4/17/2013 8:00:00 PM

                                       [Not After]
                                         4/22/2016 8:00:00 AM

                                       [Thumbprint]
                                         CA87AB342FBD2B07FF6642FAE1B6F9A685914BC8

Identifier                           : {sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com/ccuniversity_sso}
LastMonitoredTime                    : 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM
LastPublishedPolicyCheckSuccessful   : 
LastUpdateTime                       : 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM
MetadataUrl                          : 
MonitoringEnabled                    : False
Name                                 : tms
NotBeforeSkew                        : 0
Notes                                : 
OrganizationInfo                     : 
ImpersonationAuthorizationRules      : c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarysid",
                                        Issuer =~ "^(AD AUTHORITY|SELF AUTHORITY|LOCAL AUTHORITY)$" ] => issue(store="_
                                       ProxyCredentialStore",types=("http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/
                                       permit"),query="isProxySid({0})", param=c.Value );
                                       c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid", I
                                       ssuer =~ "^(AD AUTHORITY|SELF AUTHORITY|LOCAL AUTHORITY)$" ] => issue(store="_Pr
                                       oxyCredentialStore",types=("http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/pe
                                       rmit"),query="isProxySid({0})", param=c.Value );
                                       c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/proxytrustid
                                       ", Issuer =~ "^SELF AUTHORITY$" ] => issue(store="_ProxyCredentialStore",types=(
                                       "http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/permit"),query="isProxyTrustP
                                       rovisioned({0})", param=c.Value );
ProtocolProfile                      : WsFed-SAML
RequestSigningCertificate            : {[Subject]
                                         CN=*.uat.firstmarblehead.com, OU=Information Technology, O="First Marblehead E
                                       ducation Resources, Inc.", L=Boston, S=Massachusetts, C=US

                                       [Issuer]
                                         CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US

                                       [Serial Number]
                                         0FF7E7A675A284662D016D88667AB41F

                                       [Not Before]
                                         4/17/2013 8:00:00 PM

                                       [Not After]
                                         4/22/2016 8:00:00 AM

                                       [Thumbprint]
                                         24EC80DB593EAFB2828D779562EA8CED42D76846
                                       }
EncryptedNameIdRequired              : False
SignedSamlRequestsRequired           : True
SamlEndpoints                        : {Microsoft.IdentityServer.PowerShell.Resources.SamlEndpoint, Microsoft.IdentityS
                                       erver.PowerShell.Resources.SamlEndpoint, Microsoft.IdentityServer.PowerShell.Res
                                       ources.SamlEndpoint, Microsoft.IdentityServer.PowerShell.Resources.SamlEndpoint}
SamlResponseSignature                : AssertionOnly
SignatureAlgorithm                   : http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
TokenLifetime                        : 0
```

**Here is the decrypted/decoded saml. This is the post to our server, the IDP:**

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                    ID="s2eed242413a54b59b47903b814912ab1e84144944"
                    Version="2.0"
                    IssueInstant="2013-11-05T17:17:15Z"
                    Destination="https://auth.ccuniversity.edu/adfs/ls/"
                    ForceAuthn="false"
                    IsPassive="false"
                    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com/openam/Consumer/metaAlias/fmdrealm001/ccuniversity_sso_sp"
                    >
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com/ccuniversity_sso</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                        Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"
                        SPNameQualifier="sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com/ccuniversity_sso"
                        AllowCreate="true"
                        />
    <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                                 Comparison="exact"
                                 >
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

**Here is what the browser posts to their server, the SP**

```
<samlp:Response ID="_13d60ca8-b098-4373-96e3-e344668312f6"
                Version="2.0"
                IssueInstant="2013-11-05T17:17:40.234Z"
                Destination="https://sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com/openam/Consumer/metaAlias/fmdrealm001/ccuniversity_sso_sp"
                Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
                InResponseTo="s2eed242413a54b59b47903b814912ab1e84144944"
                xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                >
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://auth.ccuniversity.edu/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#_13d60ca8-b098-4373-96e3-e344668312f6">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <ds:DigestValue>8a98Uanf5TQZNwTEGU46itoq4Nc=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>aesO2KDvxadT+O2z3P84c190vBPOcHYKTZjP3Sow41iRNaMo09Tz1ERLSUw0/W3g+a67D/l5ZL5SsncsQCvhVLKwGy/JO1J1fHZuzxQ5YgoRqznYQWVUVI8x1G6ZTXuLFsnj7M5FJZNsv//uGwpPmdj/6+p7gvzkhX5mE6tCHeltKD7LDXwaO6O2XwpGNuUiYr8Zix27ZpEoVtRXrZLuSdkBhWvALyDt79MsYMRfe88FWEnWxImIMPmc/+JAj4Wnw7cSh1eSc51n2h4Ke69J2tpiiz/TgTe+N2rMDTfmHHljk6TPt1eNxMIDPIMZE1yA0NBP4QU/xf+PktNmz+rx2g==</ds:SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester">
            <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:InvalidNameIDPolicy" />
        </samlp:StatusCode>
    </samlp:Status>
</samlp:Response>
```

**Here is the error shown in the browser:**

```
GET https://sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: amlbcookie=03; BIGipServerUAT.sso.firstmarblehead.com-HTTP=1548095916.20480.0000

HTTP/?.? 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 05 Nov 2013 17:17:40 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Red Hat Enterprise Web Server)
Content-Length: 325
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

**Here are the only two logs in the AD FS Tracing --> Debug category that seem important. This one is an "Information log"**

```
Date:          10/25/2013 2:32:50 PM
Event ID:      49
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      ADFSSamlProtocol
User:          CBC\adfsuser
Computer:      domainserver2.cincybible.priv
Description:
Response: Id='_36e6dc52-2c10-40d6-8c7c-be8340812130', InResponseTo='s21d64ddbc5730da20e41936d9059bdbcf8800fa40', Status='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester(urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:InvalidNameIDPolicy)', Destination='https://sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com/openam/Consumer/metaAlias/fmdrealm001/ccuniversity_sso_sp': error response created
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="AD FS 2.0 Tracing" Guid="{f1aa12b3-dba2-4cab-b909-2c2b7afcf1fd}" />
    <EventID>49</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000200</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-10-25T18:32:50.360003000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>92</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{4DD6736A-7793-4261-BF76-DC5F84FCE6EE}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="5068" ThreadID="5636" ProcessorID="1" KernelTime="3" UserTime="15" />
    <Channel>AD FS 2.0 Tracing/Debug</Channel>
    <Computer>domainserver2.cincybible.priv</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-617894710-599159305-1136263860-26051" />
  </System>
  <UserData>
    <Event xmlns:auto-ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ActiveDirectoryFederationServices/2.0/Events">
      <EventData>Response: Id='_36e6dc52-2c10-40d6-8c7c-be8340812130', InResponseTo='s21d64ddbc5730da20e41936d9059bdbcf8800fa40', Status='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester(urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:InvalidNameIDPolicy)', Destination='https://sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com/openam/Consumer/metaAlias/fmdrealm001/ccuniversity_sso_sp': error response created</EventData>
    </Event>
  </UserData>
</Event>
```

**This one is an error log:**

```
Log Name:      AD FS 2.0 Tracing/Debug
Source:        AD FS 2.0 Tracing
Date:          10/25/2013 2:32:50 PM
Event ID:      47
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      ADFSSamlProtocol
User:          CBC\adfsuser
Computer:      domainserver2.cincybible.priv
Description:
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.InvalidNameIdPolicyException: MSIS1000: The SAML request contained a NameIDPolicy that was not satisfied by the issued token. Requested NameIDPolicy: AllowCreate: True Format: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient SPNameQualifier: sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com/ccuniversity_sso. Actual NameID properties: null.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SamlProtocolService.Issue(IssueRequest issueRequest)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SamlProtocolService.ProcessRequest(Message requestMessage)
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="AD FS 2.0 Tracing" Guid="{f1aa12b3-dba2-4cab-b909-2c2b7afcf1fd}" />
    <EventID>47</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000200</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-10-25T18:32:50.309219800Z" />
    <EventRecordID>88</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{4DD6736A-7793-4261-BF76-DC5F84FCE6EE}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="5068" ThreadID="5636" ProcessorID="2" KernelTime="3" UserTime="12" />
    <Channel>AD FS 2.0 Tracing/Debug</Channel>
    <Computer>domainserver2.cincybible.priv</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-617894710-599159305-1136263860-26051" />
  </System>
  <UserData>
    <Event xmlns:auto-ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ActiveDirectoryFederationServices/2.0/Events">
      <EventData>Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.InvalidNameIdPolicyException: MSIS1000: The SAML request contained a NameIDPolicy that was not satisfied by the issued token. Requested NameIDPolicy: AllowCreate: True Format: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient SPNameQualifier: sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com/ccuniversity_sso. Actual NameID properties: null.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SamlProtocolService.Issue(IssueRequest issueRequest)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SamlProtocolService.ProcessRequest(Message requestMessage)</EventData>
    </Event>
  </UserData>
</Event>
```

Anyone done this or have an idea on to do it?

---

So we made some progress by changing rules in ADFS (the IDP) and in OpenAM  (the SP). We now get an error regarding certificates which we are optimistic we can resolve.

Here are the exact updated rules:

```
Rule 1
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"), query = ";mail;{0}", param = c.Value);
```

Rule 2

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient", Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/spnamequalifier"] = "sso.uat.firstmarblehead.com/ccuniversity_sso");
```

This forum describes the changes made to OpenAM

http://list-archives.org/2012/09/29/openam-forgerock-org/openam-and-adfs-fedration/f/1331885749

Specifically note this section:

```
"> >>> Peter Major <peter.major@forgerock.com> 9/29/2012 3:04 AM >>>
>
> Go to the Federation page, and try to remove persistent nameid-format
> from both SP and IdP configuration (one of seems to be on the top of the
> nameid format, but adfs doesn't like it).
> The OpenAM side of the error is probably at handling the SAML error
> response, can you please provide the HTTP flow (or the SAML
> requests/responses)?"
```